# Проблема с метками, содержащими кирилицу

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, метки, кириллица

В списке меток не работают ссылки для меток, содержащих (или полностью состоящих) русские буквы. Например, для [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/хэшкод](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%D1%85%D1%8D%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4) срабатывает редирект:

```
<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="/questions">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>
```

Учитывая большое количество таких меток, большая часть функционала не работает.

Comment: Более того, кириллическую метку вообще нельзя создать (отбраковывается regexp-ом?).

Comment: На японском сайте аналогичные метки работают http://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/正規表現

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Начали исследовать вопрос. Достаточно странное поведение учитывая, что кириллические метки есть на форуме о изучении русского языка https://russian.stackexchange.com/

**Обновление**

Поправили.

Comment: спасибо, работает )